# why jquery pattern match method is firing only for the first element

Tags: jquery, pattern-matching, expression, match

i am passing field id in this function

```
function expDuration(id) {

     if(id.match(/-exp_dol/g).length > 0 || id.match(/-exp_doj/g).length > 0){
                alert(id);
          }
```

now if i pass id that have pattern "-exp_dol" it alert me the id 
but if i pass id that have pattern "-exp_doj" it doesnot alert me the id

now the funny thing is in the if statement if i write  the exp_doj first and then OR operator then the exp_dol
like this

```
if(id.match(/-exp_doj/g).length > 0 || id.match(/-exp_dol/g).length > 0){
                alert(id);
          }
```

and pass the id that match "-exp_doj" it alerts me while for "-exp_dol" it doesnot alert

so is this right that match method is only firing for the first element and not for the second or i am doing it wrong....Please advice me

Comment: Look in the browsers's error console. The error message should easily help solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try to use , this worked for me

```
id="this is -exp_dol sdgfsd";
if(id.match(/(?:-exp_doj|-exp_dol)/ig))
{
  alert('present');
}
```

after reading the comment . this will aslo work. I have posted the code that worked for me . We can use this without `ig` or with only `g`

```
id="this is -exp_dol sdgfsd";
    if(id.match(/(?:-exp_doj|-exp_dol)/))
    {
      alert('present');
    }
```

here is a working js fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rhqgksL/)

Comment: Not my downvote, but why the lookahead? Why did you add the `i` flag even though the original code doesn't have it? Why did you keep the `g` flag? Why not just `/-exp_do[jl]/`?

Comment: `ig` is used in regex to search in the full string . if the keyword exist inside the whole string .it will also work with `g` only and also work without this .

Comment: `i` means case insensitive search. It doesn't have anything to do with "searching in the full string."

Comment: I don't know much about regex. this solution worked for me so i have post this . If you or the down-voter have better solution then you can post that rather then down-voting or arguments .the solution is working very well for both conditions and fullfill the question requirements . so whats wrong ??

Comment: I am interesting to learn . Post the answer i'll learn from that.

Comment: I posted it in the first comment (`/-exp_do[jl]/`).